# Simultaneity and Tachyons

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, causality, tachyon

I open this question because the discussion on @Demigan's question did not come to a satisfactory conclusion.

One of the best discussions on tachyon relativity that I’ve seen is by David Bohm in his book *The Special Theory of Relativity, New York, 1965*. 
It is available for download here: https://epdf.pub/queue/special-theory-of-relativity4ba0cc5d0dc7aacebe7c1737a434f84e37001.html

He writes in chapter 28 - **The Question of Causality and the Maximum
Speed of Propagation of Signals in Relativity Theory**

> “When two events are in each other’s absolute elsewhere, so that they can have no physical contact, it makes no difference whether we say they are before or after each other. Their relative time order has a purely conventional character, in the sense that one can ascribe any such order that is convenient, as long as one applies his conventions in a
>   consistent manner”.

Is there more to it, or is this still the standard relativistic view?
I attach his Fig. 27-2, if it will show in the post.

[image]

Comment: could you provide the link to demigans question?

Comment: @Umaxo - Demagin's question:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/540383/why-does-relativity-first-slow-down-time-for-the-object-as-it-approaches-lightsp/540396#540396

Comment: as far as I know, that is still standard view. It gets even more recognition in general relativity, since curvature of spacetime make this conventionality much more evident and dealing with it almost necessity.

Comment: anyway I found the bohm book amazing gem and thanks for it. But I have one comment for the chapter 28. Note he comes to contradiction with faster than light travel only by use of free will. In the universe with no free will, but governed by physical laws, the contradiction is not necessary.

Comment: If we listen to Roger Penrose, free will  may be caused by quantum events in the brain, so it may be covered by 'physical laws'... ;)

Comment: yes it may. Or it may not. It is an open question and we should not be so quick to judge as Bohm does in the chapter.